# What data is the commit parameter in increment()?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, action

The parameter commit is mentioned in the [Vuex documentation](https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/zh/guide/actions.html#%E5%88%86%E5%8F%91-action)

What data is the commit parameter in increment()?

[https://sm.ms/image/A5qnBI3jSKU4pP1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Zt3.png)

Comment: It's the name of the mutation function, check this : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Answer (score 0):

Actions api's [Docs](https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions) here

It describe what context is in action

```js
{
  state,      // same as `store.state`, or local state if in modules
  rootState,  // same as `store.state`, only in modules
  commit,     // same as `store.commit`
  dispatch,   // same as `store.dispatch`
  getters,    // same as `store.getters`, or local getters if in modules
  rootGetters // same as `store.getters`, only in modules
}
```

And with ES6 [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

It is equivalent to the following code

```js
increment(context){
  const {commit} = context;
  // ...
}
```

So the `commit` is same as [`store.commit`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#commit)

```
commit(type: string, payload?: any, options?: Object)
commit(mutation: Object, options?: Object)
```

Commit a mutation. options can have root: true that allows to commit root mutations in namespaced modules. Details